# How to extend AsyncFileUpload class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am trying to extend the AsyncFileUploadEventArgs class. below is my code

```
public class abc : AsyncFileUploadEventArgs
{
    public abc() { }
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public String FileName { get { return fileName; } }
    private string fileName;

    public string FileSize { get { return fileSize; } }
    private string fileSize;

    public AsyncFileUploadState State { get { return State; } }
    private AsyncFileUploadState state;

    public string StatusMessage { get { return statusMessage; } }
    private string statusMessage;

    public abc(AsyncFileUploadState state, string statusMessage, string filename, 
                                                                   string filesize)
    {
        this.fileName = filename;
        this.state = state;
        this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
        this.fileSize = filesize;
    }
}
```

MetaData of `AsyncFileUploadEventArgs` class

```
public class AsyncFileUploadEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public AsyncFileUploadEventArgs();
    public AsyncFileUploadEventArgs(AsyncFileUploadState state, string statusMessage, string filename, string filesize);

    public string FileName { get; }
    public string FileSize { get; }
    public AsyncFileUploadState State { get; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; }
}
```

Below is the `AsyncFileUpload UploadedComplete` handler

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, abc e)
{
}
```

Below is the user control for AsyncFileUpload

```
<cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" 
    runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
```

My motive is - I am trying to validate the Height and Width of the selected file in the `AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete` handler. I am doing it server side because Height and Width are not available in the `AsyncFileUploadEventArgs` class.

So, I was thinking to add new property called Height and assign it's value server side and access it client side.

By extending the class it is giving me below error

> No overload for 'AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'

Can you please tell the reason ?

Answer (score -2):

Should be using this argument for the UploadedComplete event:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am trying to add a new property in the extended class in place of `AsyncFileUploadEventArgs` class

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. The reason why you're getting the error is because of the one I've stated which fixes that. Was that your question or asking how to extend the actual control?